# Most concise way of cycling through elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the HTML below, whats the most concise way of cycling through all elements while toggling the classes `active` and `hidden` when the next button is pressed?

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">        
    First Element <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">        
    Second Element <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden">        
    Third Element <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can assume that the class `hidden` hides the element.

This is the most concise way I could think of:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
   var $li = $(this).parent().toggleClass('active hidden'),
   $nextLi = $li.is(':last-child') ? $li.siblings(':first') : $li.next();
   $nextLi.toggleClass('active hidden');
});
```

Comment: given no code...what have you tried?

Comment: It's below. I'm answering my own question.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm showing what I tried below! I couldn't find this question when I googled it (only similar problems but with a different markup)

Answer (score 2):

Probably more golfing than concise, but still

```
var elems = $('li').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).is('.next') ) 
        $([this.nextElementSibling||elems.first(), this]).toggleClass('active hidden');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/d4gqs1jy/2/)

or

```
$('.next').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.active+li, li:first').last().add('.active').toggleClass('active hidden');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/d4gqs1jy/4/)

for consistency and readability, I'd do

```
$('.next').on('click', function(e) {
    var li   = $(this).closest('li'),    // this LI
        lis  = li.siblings().addBack(),  // all LI's
        act  = lis.filter('.active'),    // active LI
        next = act.next();               // next LI

    if ( next.length === 0 ) next = lis.first(); // if no next, get first

    li.add( next ).toggleClass('active hidden');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/d4gqs1jy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.next').click(function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent().toggleClass('active hidden'),
     $nextLi = $li.is(':last-child') ? $li.siblings(':first') : $li.next();

  $nextLi.toggleClass('active hidden');
});
```

In short you use `toggleClass` to switch between `active` and `hidden` and the pseudo-selectors `:first` and `:last-child` to determine whether or not you should cycle back to the first element.

Comment: That assumes you click them in order, and that the `hidden` class probably hides them, right. If you click them out of order, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a position attribute

```
<ul>
  <li class="active" position="0">        
    First Element <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden" position="1">        
    Second Element <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden" position="2">        
    Third Element <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
  </li>
</ul>

var max = 3;
$('.next').click(function() {
    var position = $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('hidden').attr('position');
    var nextPosition = Number(position) + 1 % max;
    $('li.hidden[position="' + nextPosition + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: No, you are adding the class active to the anchor element.

Comment: yeah opps, just changed it

Comment: This does not cycle through the elements.  You are always selecting the same element. `$(this).parent()` always adds the `active` class to the parent element of the next button (instead of adding it to its sibling)

Comment: Okay, didn't really understand what you meant. Heres a better answer

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents worth:

```
   $('.next').click(function(){
        var $parent=$(this).parent().toggleClass('active hidden'),
            $next = $parent.next().length ? $parent.next() : $parent.siblings(':first');
        $next.toggleClass('active hidden');            
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cnxwugjr/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why toggle classes? Just set the css so only the first item is displayed, and move the item to the end of the list when it is clicked.

```
$('ul').on('click', '.next', function() {
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $li.parent().append($li);
});
```

CSS

```
ul>li { display: none; }
ul>li:first-child { display: block; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp26fdkf/1/)

---

But if you must toggle classes:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.next', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').children(':first,.active,.active+*').slice(-2).toggleClass('active hidden');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1cp9w86/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var dir = $('.active').next().length ? 'next' : 'siblings';
    $('.active').toggleClass("active hidden")[dir]().first().toggleClass("active hidden");
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/zx2u660s/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better and shorter version of the code that I posted earlier. I posted this separately because it uses a different method of selection and results in siginificantly shorter code. I figured it warranted its own answer because it is both more concise and it uses CSS selectors instead of jQuery functions, a method that I don't think has been discussed here yet.

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.active, '+($('.active+li').length?'.active+li':'li:first')).toggleClass("active hidden");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/f01zxwvs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not much jQuery, but quite concise and conveys the meaning pretty well:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li > .next', function(e) {
    var li = this.parentNode;
    li.className = "hidden";
    (li.nextElementSibling || li.parentNode.firstElementChild).className = "active";
});
```

([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxm0kaxL/1/))